# browser caching interfering with css style changes?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, caching

I've got a small problem on my site which hopefully you fine folk can help with. In order to improve Google page load speeds on my site (wheelingit.us) I installed browser caching in my .htaccess file according to this link:
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Htaccess_tricks#Faster_Page_Load_Times_.2F_Bandwidth_Saver

My pagespeed definitely improved. However now I notice that when I change css styling or update text in one of the side-widgets it doesn't show on my web page. I'm thinking this is linked to the browser caching?

Anyway to make my css & widget box text changes appear on the page while still taking advantage of the browser caching? Or do I need to remove the browser caching altogether?

Nina

Comment: does doing a force refresh help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: you need to do a 'force refresh' - it happens all the time in web development.   I would not recommend removing browser caching unless absolutely necessary

Comment: these headers also might help http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb (I'm still in learning stages), but how exactly do I do a force refresh?

Comment: @Wheelingit  CTRL+R or CTRL+F5 does it

Comment: @ochi So sadly, the force refresh doesn't seem to work. The "old" styles are still showing on the page despite the "new" style in my CSS stylesheet. I only made a simple change (changed the paragraph margins from 25px to 20px), but the new style just isn't showing up.

Comment: @Wheelingit unusual! are you sure the new version (with the changes) are loaded onto the server and your page is calling *it*? (happens to me all the time: I modify a file and forget to load it to the server OR modify the wrong file thinking it is the correct one)

Comment: @ochi I believe so. I mean, when I look at the file in EDITOR on Wordpress I see the changes there. Also, just to be sure I opened an FTP window directly to my site and opened the file from there too. It also shows the changes. They're just not showing on the actual page.

Comment: Ah! wordpress (why didn't you say so? :) ).  Then it is probably server caching, do you have a server-caching plugin installed? you may have to purge the file from the server's plugin

Comment: @ochi hmmm....you might have hit on something (and I apologize for not including everything in my qs). I'm on Wordpress and hosting on Dreampress which has Varnish caching on it. That's probably it. I think I need to go purge the server cache.

Comment: Ha! no worries... that's how troubleshooting issues like this work... process of elimination :) - have a look at [this varnish purge page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/)

Comment: @ochi thanks for you help, esp. for a newbie like me :)

Comment: @Wheelingit glad to help... we were all newbies once... I know the struggles and I still struggle with other topics that I am new to... no worries... Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @Wheelingit one more thing... For the benefit of other users, once you figure out the answer, don't forget to either mark an existing and correct answer as accepted or add your solution as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a query string to your .css file that you can force to update when you make changes.

something like stylesheet.css?v=1.0.

You can then just increment the v when you made changes.

Comment: AHA! Yes, I can change the version. Didn't think of that duh! Thanks I will try that.

Comment: What if the page itself is cached?

Comment: @tribe84 bummer. This didn't work. Changed the version on my stylesheet, but for some reason my browser isn't pulling the new version yet. I tried force refresh (CTRL-F5) and it still isn't showing the new version. I think I might have some kind of weird caching issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion, it seems that you are using a Varnish - server-side- caching solution for performance optimization of your Wordpress site.  Doing a purge on the plugin's cache should solve the issue.

To purge all CSS files from cache manually, open a command or terminal console and type:

```
$ curl -X PURGE "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/.*\.css"
```

You can follow instructions here for more examples:
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/DreamPress#Manually_Purging_the_Varnish_Cache_Via_SSH

There are other wordpress plugins that can help you do this, but they require you to install them which may be more overhead than required:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/